# Creating component, getting Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native

Trying to create a basic component in React Native and getting an error.

Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I'm just trying to create a component that will be an image, but with some resizing on it.

The `<ActivityImage>` component is what I'm trying to make:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
let windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

export default class ActivityImage extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Image source={source} style={{width: windowWidth}} />
      )
    }
  }
```

The app code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StatusBar,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import styles from './assets/styles';

import { Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, Slide4 } from './assets/content';
import { ActivityImage } from './components/activityImage';    
    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
      }

      static navigationOptions = {
          header: null,
        }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar hidden />
        <ActivityImage source={require('./assets/images/0.jpg')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigation = () => (
  <SimpleAppNavigator  />
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigation/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing it correctly?

Comment: probably not, but I can't figure out what the issue is.  The code is right out of a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you import the missed components like `<View>`, `<StatusBar>` and ...
You should use your `props` for getting the source for your component. And you should define a height for your image, in this example I make it 200. In this way your component will be like this:

```
export default class ActivityImage extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Image source={this.props.source} style={{width: windowWidth, height: 200}}/>
    )
  }
}
```